# using Fourier Transforms to solve the question.

Tags: fourier-transform

I am given a question of Fourier Transform:

$$  e^{2(t-1)}u(t-1)       $$
My teacher solved it by using the formula which I couldn't understand so I tried to apply the properties on it.
Now I have solved it by the following method:

$$  e^{2(t)}u(t) \rightarrow   \frac{1}{2+j\omega}       $$

Now we know that: 
$$\delta(t-t_0) \rightarrow          e^{-j\omega t_0}         $$ 
So I used the above property on $u(t-1)$ and got the following answer which is same as my teacher got, which is:

$$      \frac{e^{-j\omega}}{2+j\omega}         $$

Is my method correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your definition of the Fourier transform is
$$
\hat f(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(t)e^{j\omega t}\ \mathsf dt,
$$
then yes, your answer is correct. We can use a change of variables $s=t+1$ to compute
\begin{align}
\hat f(\omega) &= \int_1^\infty e^{-2(t+1)}e^{j\omega t}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= e^{-j\omega}\int_0^\infty e^{-2s}e^{j\omega s}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= e^{-j\omega}\cdot\frac{1}{2+j\omega}.
\end{align}